# Spring MVC @NumberFormat Percent with Decimals

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, number-formatting, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring MVC (4.1.6.RELEASE), with Thymeleaf (2.1.4.RELEASE). My Entity class has a percentage field stored as `float`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="loans")
public class Loan {
    private float percentage;
    ...

    @NumberFormat(style=NumberFormat.Style.PERCENT)
    @Column(name="percentage")
    public float getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }
    public void setPercentage(float percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
    ...
}
```

My view uses the Thymeleaf Spring dialect to bind this bean to the form.

```
<form th:object="${loan}" th:action="@{/form-handler}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{percentage}" placeholder="e.g. 1.5%" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The form binding works fine upon submission.  An input value of "12.675%" is bound to the bean and saved to the db as "0.12675", but when displaying in an edit form Spring's `@NumberFormat` annotation automatically rounds to 13% when using `NumberFormat.Style.PERCENT`. I want to show the fractional percentage points, i.e. "12.675%".

I thought about writing a separate getter on my Entity (e.g. getPercentFormatted), but then the `th:field="*{percentFormatted}` field would not bind properly in my Controller.  I suppose I could write an additional setter as well, that would divide by 100 and set the property, but I don't love that approach.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to `@NumberFormat` an attribute `pattern` with an appropriate pattern

From http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.html

> For custom formatting, set the pattern() attribute to be the number
>   pattern, such as #, ###.##.
>
> Each attribute is mutually exclusive, so only set one attribute per
>   annotation instance (the one most convenient one for your formatting
>   needs). When the pattern attribute is specified, it takes precedence
>   over the style attribute. When no annotation attributes are specified,
>   the default format applied is style-based with a style of
>   NumberFormat.Style.NUMBER.

Comment: This won't work because you also have to multiply the property value by 100 to present 0.12675 as 12.675%.  Java offers the `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()` which does this, and includes settings for decimal precision, but `@NumberFormat` doesn't include attributes which can manipulate those settings.